# Encoding an array of CLLocation in Swift crashes the compiler?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift class that seems to work fine, except when I try to implement NSCoding. The line that seems to be giving me an issue is:

```
        aCoder.encodeObject(runSamples, forKey: "runSamples")
```

If I comment this line out, everything compiles fine. However, uncommenting it in Xcode results in:

Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %201 = bitcast i32 %200 to %objc_object*, !dbg !241
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1

Uncommenting the line Playground just causes the app to crash.

I assume this is a compiler issue, but I want to see if there was something I'm obviously missing before reporting to Apple.

Full class:

```
class RunRecord: NSObject {
    let startDate: NSDate
    var endDate: NSDate?
    var runSamples: CLLocation[]

    var currentSpeed: CLLocationDistance {
    return self.runSamples[runSamples.endIndex - 1].speed
    }

    init(startDate: NSDate) {
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.runSamples = CLLocation[]()
        super.init()
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        startDate = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("startDate") as NSDate
        endDate = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("endDate") as? NSDate
        runSamples = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("runSamples") as CLLocation[]
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(startDate, forKey: "startDate")
        aCoder.encodeObject(endDate, forKey: "endDate")
        aCoder.encodeObject(runSamples, forKey: "runSamples")
    }

    func addSample(sample: CLLocation) {
        runSamples.append(sample)
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling it? That is, how are you initialising the NSCoder prior to calling encodeWithCoder? It works fine in my playground - I'm using NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData:)

Comment: From what I can tell, it's the compiler crashing, meaning I'm not even getting a chance to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that the Swift array was being automatically bridged to Objective-C. This fixes the issue:

```
aCoder.encodeObject(runSamples.bridgeToObjectiveC(), forKey: "runSamples")
```